# Put file in specific directory when sending over socket.io

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I have a `File` (.png file to be specific) which I am trying to put it into a specific directory.

From http://socket.io/blog/introducing-socket-io-1-0/#binary it states the following code can be used to send a file:

```
socket.emit('uploadFile', { file: myFile});
```

Now in node.js I try the following:

```
.on('uploadFile', co.wrap(function* (data) {
    var fs = require('fs');
    fs.writeFile(__dirname + '/public/avatar/myFile.png', data.file, {
        flag: "w"
    }, function (err) {
        if (err) {
            return console.log(err);
        }
        console.log("The file was saved!");
    });
}))
```

This creates a file, however the file isn't readable. I'm guessing I am saving the file on node.js in the wrong was. Since it's already a file I think I'm trying to write that file to a new file.

How do I get `data.file` to the location `/public/avatar/myFile.png`.

Comment: What do you mean by "This creates a file, however the file isn't readable"? Is the file created? What does "not readable" mean? No permissions? Incorrect content? Do you get any errors? Did the file exist prior to you writing to it? Have you checked that `data.file` actually contains what you expect? If the file is created, but not in the right place, where is it created? Does the directory you want to create the file in already exist? You need to be a bit more explicit if you want people to help you.

Comment: @jcaron A file "myFile.png" is created. But when opening it in an image viewer it's not an image, just blank. The file is created in the correct directory. If you read the documentation I linked it should be correct, the actual `File`. Some people must read more.

Comment: So, again, did the file exist prior to you writing to it? Does your node.js script have permissions to write to it? Does `data.file` actually contain what you expect it to? What does the file actually contain? What size does it have?

Comment: @jcaron No! Hence the "w" flag (should create it if it does not exist). Afaiak it should overwrite the old contents of the file. I just read the `fs.writeFile` specifications and I apparantly need to convert the `File` into a `Buffer`. I apologize about what the file is, it's a `.png file`.